# Storing Array elements in an order specified by the user

Tags: arrays

I'd like users of my application to be able to rearrange a number of elements in an array into an order of their choice, while maintaining the original array structure. What's the best representation of this data? I've considered using decimals (e.g when moving element 4 between element 2 and 3, it gets a value of 2.5) however it seems like this would quickly get complex when working with many values, and may have an unnecessary overhead. Is there a simpler solution to this problem that I've overlooked?

Comment: @BoltClock I don't think that makes much of a difference, as this is a pretty general question.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Actually I think it does: Many languages do not support non-integer array indexes.

Comment: It's in Javascript, although at the moment I'm more interested in a high level answer than an implementation.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I don't think he's talking about array indices, but rather about changing the data, but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

How are they doing the reordering? If it is some kind of drag-and-drop or button to swap two elements or to move one element up or down, the most logical way is to simply swap those two elements in the array.

Comment: It'll likely be drag and drop, though the framework I'm using will dynamically sort the array on the fly based on a specified property, and I'd like to maintain the original order if possible.